# How can i add footer props to Vuetify 3 data-table-server component?

Tags: vue.js, datatable, pagination, vuetify.js, footer

I use vue 3 with vuetify 3, in vuetify 2 version i was use footer props to set itemsPerPage option.

In vuetify 3 i could not use it.

```
<v-data-table-server
:footer-props="{
  'items-per-page-options': itemsPerPageOptions,
  showFirstLastPage: true,
  disableItemsPerPage,
}"
>
</v-data-table-server>
```

Also i could not find any information in vuetify [api](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table-server/).

Comment: Yes, as of Vuetify 3.1.18, this has not (yet) found its way into the labs version.

Answer (score 1):

add props

```
<v-data-table
:headers="headers"
items="editItem"
item-value="name"

    itemsPerPageText="Items per page"

disableItemsPerPage="false"
class="elevation-1"
>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).